# Is it possible to pass querysets from multiple models(tables) in a single list() method of viewsets.ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to pass two querysets in a single list method, I want something like this...

```
def list(self,request):
    queryset1 = Algorithm1.objects.all()
    serializer1 = Algorithm1Serializer(queryset,many=True)
    queryset2 = Algorithm2.objects.all()
    serializer2 = Algorithm2Serializer(queryset,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How to achieve that? Thnks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a new dictionary

```
result = {'serializer1': serializer1.data, 'serializer2': serializer2.data} 
return response(result)
```

Comment: if this is working as expected, please mark this answer as accepted answer so other can be benefited from this.

Comment: thanks Tarun, it works. I am new to drf , so doubt is: can I apply same way of returnig dict  to retrieve() as well?

Comment: Nopes you've to intercept response then use dict to initialize serializer for each key and then use it accordingly.